Techniques for writing papers when one has dyslexia
What are techniques for writing well/improving your writing/writing faster when you have dyslexia for highly complex and deep material?
For this question I am specifically asking about techniques that work well for dyslexic people rather than general techniques for writing. The reason for this is that things that work well for neurotypicals when writing academic papers can easily be found on the web, and probably in many questions on this site. However for writing with dyslexia, the web is saturated by how to write at a primary/high school level. While I don't believe there is no overlap between good techniques for people with and without dyslexia, standard approaches can be added to any approaches given here.
The other reason is that standard approaches may have a huge barrier to application when you are dyslexic. For example, a common suggestion I have heard is read a paper and take note of what language/phrases you liked in the paper. However, I recently realised I'd never really read an academic paper due to the dyslexia.
To provide insight, I have read many papers (while completing my PhD and post-doc) and comprehended the meaning/seen the big structure of the paper, but don't read the actual sentences. I observed this when asking a friend for an example of a well written paper from my field and read it both as a normal paper and with a modified text supposedly for dyslexic people (opendyslexic). When reading it as a normal paper it seemed standard to me, but with the altered font the text seemed to have been written by a high school student (i.e. it is written using simple words and short sentences). This does lead to an answer whereby you just replace the font in papers, but finding an efficient workflow that allows that (particularly when mathematical formula and figures are in the text). I would consider an answer that makes this efficient within the scope of this question.
I expect there are other issues beyond the one I described above that limits the effectiveness of normal approaches, but these differences aren't obvious to me since it is always hard to see the difference between how you experience the world and how others experience it.

In my specific case I also have auditory processing difficulties, which means answers that say listen to papers instead or use dictation tools probably won't be as helpful for me specifically. Therefore I would prefer techniques that avoid this kind of thing, but would consider them valid answers for this question.

I don't see how this is validly answerable here. It seems to need a professional.

I suspect there are many people that use this site who have dyslexia, suggestions of techniques that work for people who have dyslexia (or know people who have it) make valid answers. The main issue is that people may not feel like disclosing they have dyslexia, though such stigma is decreasing.

Perhaps, but you seem to be describing a very specific variation/combination.

Related: Doing a physical science or maths PhD with dyslexia

At least as far as the writing part of the question is concerned, have you tried dictation software? You won't have to worry about spelling correctly in that case.

@WolfgangBangerth, I suspect that is less useful in math, however.

This is not a dyslexia specific comment, but I find that it really helps to present the paper, which focuses you on key points to communicate. Then gradually convert to written paper with those points as topic sentences etc.

Most universities have writing centers, that is ,groups that help students improve their writing skills. While these are designed for undergraduates, some of them might have experience helping dyslexic students.

A good friend of mine has had luck with the following:

Have paper read out loud by a human or computer. Computers in many cases can slow down the speed of reading, while humans pronounce technical words better and do inflection to indicate the start and end of ideas. If dictating, make sure to use a technical dictation tool that's field-specific, so you can dictate equations etc.
When possible, write electronically with light text on a dark background. Do not use justified text to allow your eyes to better recognize the lengths of words. (I have no idea if this would work, but Word allows you to change the spacing of letters which could help you focus on fewer at a time?)
Establish the sections of the paper first, written as an outline, and have at least the story in your head. "Flow" is universally an indicator of great writing.
Focus on the figures.
Ask someone you trust to improve your phrasing once you get the bones laid out. Or, have them act as a sounding board/interpreter: Tell them what you want to say and have them suggest phrasings until you get what you like. Then one of you types it out.

I was asked to be the human in #5 for my friend recently. Although he doesn't have auditory processing troubles, he did say that going to presentations and debating with others helped him pick up the language of the field without actually reading very much. Then the steps above let him get it onto paper. He's not a great reader, but I would say he is a great writer.
As a non-dyslexic, one of my favorite things to do to practically improve sentences once I have a paper drafted is to highlight common words like "because" or "however" with a Ctrl+F feature then use an online thesaurus to find replacements. Varied language makes your paper more enjoyable to read and can be injected at the end of the writing process. Mixing short and long sentences also helps a lot with readability for you and viewers. I read stuff out loud a lot, and listen for the meter rather than the actual words. This helps me detect when a sentence has become too long to be easily understood. Finally, copy-pasting from published works you respect is quite useful. Just be sure that you are really changing the substance so as to avoid plagiarism. But a phrase here or there, longer stuff with attribution, or just a similar structure, is ok.
For deep or highly technical writing specifically: In my experience the hardest part is getting the "if/ then/ but" or "we hypothesized/ we observed/ we concluded" statements out correctly. When struggling, I will highlight or change the text color of each part of such a statement. Then when I skim the whole manuscript, I make sure each part in red agrees, each part in blue agrees, etc. When it's really bad, I will draw diagrams for myself in a notebook showing the flow of conclusions or processes or grouping samples or measurements together. Then I just cross off each point in the notebook as I make it in the text. If you follow the diagram, you know you hit everything without having to go back and reread as much.
